# How to convert date from UTC to local time zone and reverse with Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am storing date in UTC format on my Node/express server and using Restangular to Get and post data on client. Is it possible to convert Date from UTC to local time and local time to UTC with restangular addResponseInterceptor  and addRequestInterceptor methods.

Comment: How are you looking to use the date that you need it converted to local time? If you're using Angular's datetime filters, it will use the local timezone, as specified by the browser settings (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n).

Comment: Conversely, if you do need to change the timestamp value itself, you could get the timezone offset from a date object (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp) and change your value using that to change it by the right number of milliseconds, and just throw that into Restangular's interceptors as the function you want to perform on the data.

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend checking out moment.js http://momentjs.com/ it helps when dealing with time stuff.

Comment: Did you find any way of doing this.  Migrating my app to Azure, and in UTC / Timezone hell (and yes, I know I should have done this earlier)

Answer (score 2):

This post was the solution for me.  Works great - only change I made was to add an toLocal flag, which I set to true on the Response interceptor, and false on the Request, then used moment to do the appropriate switch..

http://aboutcode.net/2013/07/27/json-date-parsing-angularjs.html

```
function convertDateStringsToDates(input, toLocal) {
  // Ignore things that aren't objects.
  if (typeof input !== "object") return input;

for (var key in input) {
    if (!input.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

    var value = input[key];
    var match;
    // Check for string properties which look like dates.
    if (typeof value === "string" && (match = value.match(regexIso8601))) {
        var milliseconds = Date.parse(match[0]);
        if (!isNaN(milliseconds)) {
            if (toLocal) {
                input[key] = moment.utc(new Date(milliseconds)).local().toDate();
            } else {
                input[key] = moment(new Date(milliseconds)).utc().toDate();
            }

        }
    } else if (typeof value === "object") {
        // Recurse into object
        convertDateStringsToDates(value, toLocal);
    }
}
return input;
```

}

then...

```
  .config([
    '$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function () {
            return {
                request: function(request) {
                    return convertDateStringsToDates(request,false);
                },

                response: function (response) {
                   // otherwise, default behaviour
                    return convertDateStringsToDates(response, true);
                }
            };
        });
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can transform String to Date (for GET) in restangular transformer, something like this

```
RestangularConfigurer
  .addElementTransformer('<RESTRESOURCENAME>', false, function (element) {
      element.createDate = new Date(element.createDate);
      return element;
  })
```